# D3 try to change data on csv import

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm importing a not-so-clean CSV file which has some rows that I must skip, and I've been able to do so successfully with filters.
However, many of the fields contain undesired characters and I have not been able to successfully remove them.

The data comes with additional characters and spaces:

```
Amount:"$286.28"
CheckDate:" 12/31/15"
```

This is what I'm attempting:

```
d3.csv("DATA2015.csv", function(csv) {
    csv.CheckDate = csv.CheckDate.substring(1);
    csv.Amount = +csv.Amount.substring(1);
    csv.Fee=+csv.Fee;
    csv = csv.filter(function(row) {
        return row['Amount'] != '';
    })
    console.log(csv[0]);
    console.log(csv[1]);
    console.log(csv[2]);
    console.log(csv[3]);
    console.log(csv[4]);
});
```

And I'm getting a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined on the substring(1) line.

Any ideas is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what happens when you console.log(csv.CheckDate, csv.Amount)?

Comment: The most likely problem is that csv.CheckDate and csv.Amount are not stings; there are some rows that may not have any values for these fields. Can you show the code for what the csv object looks like and it's properties?

Comment: Why you don't simply put on excel and make a find & replace, for all those undesirable characters? This way you sanitize your csv before read it.

Answer (score 2):

I could be oversimplifying this, but isn't `csv` an array?
So running `csv.CheckDate.substring(1)` would not make sense. Instead you'd want to loop through each member of the array and `row.CheckDate.substring(1)`, etc.

Taking that into account, try this:

```
d3.csv("DATA2015.csv", function(csv) {
  csv.forEach(function(row) {
    row.CheckDate = row.CheckDate.substring(1);
    row.Amount = +row.Amount.substring(1);
    row.Fee = +row.Fee;
  });

  csv = csv.filter(function(row) {
    return row.Amount !== '';
  });

  console.log(csv[0]);
  console.log(csv[1]);
  console.log(csv[2]);
  console.log(csv[3]);
  console.log(csv[4]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check before creating the substring. something like this.

```
csv.Amount = csv.Amount || 'Your string when data is undefined';
```

and afterwards do the string manipulation.